# Applying two or more ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 on the same bitmap

Tags: android

I got a small problem with ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 when applying more than one filter. When I apply a filter (B) it overwrites the filter (A). I wonder if it's possible to do it with ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3? Thank You!

```
mRS = android.renderscript.RenderScript.create( app.android.context );
    mInAllocation  = android.renderscript.Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, bitmap, android.renderscript.Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, android.renderscript.Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    mOutAllocation = android.renderscript.Allocation.createTyped(mRS, mInAllocation.getType());


    //A - First Filter
    let a = android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3.create(mRS, android.renderscript.Element.U8_4(mRS));
    a.setInput(mInAllocation);
    a.setCoefficients(toFloatArray([-2, -1, -0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2]));
    a.forEach(mOutAllocation);
    mOutAllocation.copyTo(this.image.bitmap._nativeObject);
    //B - Second Filter
    let b = android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3.create(mRS, android.renderscript.Element.U8_4(mRS));
    b.setInput(mInAllocation);
    b.setCoefficients(toFloatArray([-1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1]));
    b.forEach(mOutAllocation);
    mOutAllocation.copyTo(this.image.bitmap._nativeObject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use output of A for B:

```
let a = android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3.create(mRS, android.renderscript.Element.U8_4(mRS));
a.setInput(mOutAllocation); // fix here
```